# Hash integers into N roughly equal sized buckets directly based on upper bits (maintaining order)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Preferably a quick way.  The `N = 2^b` case is pretty easy.  For it, first I'd figure out how many bits are in my chosen type:

```
typedef unsigned int type;
size_t size = sizeof(type) * 8;
```

Then I would perform a right shift by the proper amount of bits to produce a hash key of the upper `b` bits.

```
type input = 0x657;
unsigned char b = 4;
unsigned char hash = input >> (size - b);
```

But what if I wanted `N = 3`?  Or any other non power of 2?  Assuming my `N` will always fit inside an `unsigned char` (so it will be 256 at most), what would be the quickest way to hash some `input`?  While keeping the buckets no more than +/- 1 difference in range, and also preserving the order of the upper bits of `input`, like the above function does.

Comment: @Joe `N = 256` buckets can be indexed by an `unsigned char` (0 to 255)

Comment: What do you mean by keeping the buckets at +/- 1 difference in size?  Are you assuming that you're distributing every integer into one of the buckets?

Comment: @templatetypedef I should have said the range going into each bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 32-bit values, do a 64-bit multiply with `N` and keep the top 32 bits. (Similarly for other sizes, although if you have 64-bit values the multiplication gets trickier.)

Here's a basic proof outline.

It's obvious that this mapping is order-preserving; the only question is how many values fall into each bucket. Now, consider some bucket `j` and find the smallest `i` which maps to that bucket. For `i` to fall into bucket `j` means that `Ni − j×232 = m` where `0 ≤ m < 232`, but if `i` is the smallest such value, `0 ≤ m < N`. (Otherwise, `i−1` would also fall into bucket `j`.)

Now, define `w = ⌊232∕N⌋`, which is equivalent to saying that `Nw − 232 = −m' where 0 ≤ m' < N`. By adding those two formulas up, we discover that `Ni + Nw - j×232 - 232 = m−m'`; simplifying, we get `N(i+w)-(j+1)×232 = m−m'` and `−N < m−m' < N`. That means that either `i + w` or `i + w + 1` is the smallest value which maps to `j + 1` (depending on whether `m − m'` is negative or not), which means that there are either `w` or `w + 1` values which map to `j`. Since that's true for any `j`, we can definitely say that there are only two bucket sizes, one of which is `⌊232∕N⌋`. It's not far from there to the assertion I made in my comment (now deleted) which is that the other possible bucket size is `⌈232∕N⌉`.

There's nothing magic about `232` in the above proof; I could have used any value `M`. But that would have made the condensed proof even hard to read.

Comment: Dividing by `N` won't work, that would be like shifting right by `b` bits in the `N = 2^b` case.  I don't have much of a problem with using a divide, but how to do the divide and keep the buckets as close to equal size as possible?

Comment: oops, that's what i get for typing while rushing. It should be divide by MAXINT/N, which will reduce to the other expression.

Comment: @user173342 Completely rewrote the answer, leaving your initial comment inscrutable. Sorry.

Comment: Couldn't this method cause the last bucket to be N larger than the rest of the buckets?

Comment: @user173342, I think this method actually reduces the roundoff errors to the minimum.